# Why Javascript returns incorrect UTC month value?

Tags: javascript

Well...to begin with...let me say I have done this a thousand times. I am simply trying to print utc time in JavaScript.

But...the value that I got is wrong.

Instead of ( 9) September, JavaScript is returning (8) for august. Since today is September 2,2014.

The UTC time would be something like: `2014-09-02 07:00:02`.

Instead of that I am getting `2014-08-02 07:00:02`.

I have included a fiddle.Please have a look at it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/iamsajeev/g7pyLtzt/1/)

Comment: its not really wrong i think, the count of month in javascript starts with zero means january is zero

Answer (score 16):

Months in JavaScript are returned as a 0 based value.

```
0 January
1 Feburary
...
8 September
9 November
...
```

Docs:

> The value returned by getUTCMonth is an integer between 0 and 11
> corresponding to the month. 0 for January, 1 for February, 2 for
> March, and so on.

Comment: @Hi_Daddy That depends on what you want to do. If you want to show your users the month: Yes. Users except January to be 1 and not 0. For internal usage I recommend not to increment by one.

Comment: So..for internal usage..what should I do? If I am not wrong...earlier when I used the same for month May a few months back,I got 5 as output. I have to pass this time variable to a function. @wumm

Comment: create a function that will convert your month in javascript to something realistic like `jsMonthToRealMonthNumber(0)` which returns 1, just always remember that you must use this function before doing something else or if you will just process it to javascript convert it back.

Comment: @Hi_Daddy I can't believe this function returned you 5 for May. But anyway, if you have already code excepting 1-based months then simply increment by one.

Comment: IDK, it was months ago.May be I am wrong. Most probably I wouldn't have noticed this at that time.

Answer (score 3):

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to universal time.

You can try using array.

```
var d = new Date()
var month = new Array(12);
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
```

...

var n = month[d.getUTCMonth()];

Answer (score 0):

Java script use 0 for January so every month will give you int value of the previous month.

So you can just add 1 in the variable where you are storing the month value and it i will work perfectly.
e.g :

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date + ":" + (month+1) + ":" + year;
```

If you wanna display date then you can see the below example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Clock</title>
    <style>

        #date{
            color: red;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "date"></div>
<script>
setInterval(displayclock,500);
    function displayclock () {
        var time = new Date ();
        var date = time.getUTCDate();
        var month =  time.getUTCMonth();
            month = month + 1;
        var year = time.getFullYear();


        
        if (month < 10){
            month = "0" + month 
        }
        if (date < 10){
            date = "0" + date 
        }
    
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = date + ":" + month + ":" + year;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Shree sure man i did, thanks for letting me know