# Javascript Date setUTCMonth works unexpectedly with certain date

Tags: javascript

I ran this script in firefox, safari and node and got the same results:

```
const date = new Date("2022-07-31T00:00:00.000Z")
console.log(date.getUTCMonth()) // 6
date.setUTCMonth(8)
console.log(date.getUTCMonth()) // should be 8 but it's 9
```

I assume it's not an issue with timezone because clearly every line of the code specifies `UTC` timezone. Interestingly, this only happens when you initiate the date object with JULY 31st.

Is this a bug? If so, is there any workaround?

Comment: Well I'm guessing this occurs because there is no September 31st (and the extra day carries over into November)? You only change the month, not day.

Comment: Working as designed. If you set the month forward, and the next month has fewer days, you get a date in the month after that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Javascript returns incorrect UTC month value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25617605/why-javascript-returns-incorrect-utc-month-value)

Comment: No Jojo, I am aware that months are 0-indexed in date object logic. Just like other people mentioned above, it was because there is no Sep 31st. FYI July 31st is one of only few dates that 2 months later rolls over to the next one(October). It should happen in December 29th~31th as well because February only has 28 days... I couldn't have even imagined this without your answers. Thanks to everyone commented!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is no September 31st, the one extra day carries over into November, making it November 1st (month 9). One could solve this by setting the day to the first:

```js
const date = new Date("2022-07-31T00:00:00.000Z");

console.log(date.getUTCMonth());

date.setUTCDate(0);
date.setUTCMonth(8);

console.log(date.getUTCMonth()); // correctly 8 now
```

And to confirm this suspicion, we can log the UTC date of your original code:

```js
const date = new Date("2022-07-31T00:00:00.000Z")
console.log(date.getUTCMonth()) // 6
date.setUTCMonth(8)
console.log(date.getUTCMonth()) // should be 8 but it's 9
console.log(date.getUTCDate()) // just as we expected, 1
```